# How to make new version updating safe in PHP OpCache?

Tags: php, opcache

My php project is now working on `Apache` with `mod_php`. I want to open `OpCache` to accelerate my code. But I'm worry about if it's safe to update the code.

1. The `validate_timestamps` should be `0`. Because the code may expire when you update new version, and this can make the code of new version call the code of old version.
2. But even if I set `validate_timestamps=0`, this can also happen. When I update the code file, one of the code file that hasn't been cached is called. And thus this code file is in new version while the caller is in old version. Maybe I can load all the code files into cache before the server start?
3. If I find a way to make sure all the files in the project dir are loaded into cache before the `Apache` start to serve requests, I can update new version code first, and then clear all the `OpCache`. But does it have an impact on those working requests? Will they run an old logic and then be switch into a new one?
4. Besides, how to clear all the `OpCache` in an atom time? If it takes time to clear all the `OpCache`, the problem is still there, right?

Can anyone help me? Thank you very much!

---

Let me show an example.

I have two files on my directory, and the Apache's working directory is also there.
The entry file is `index.php`.

```php
<?php
echo "verson 1: index";

// do some work
sleep(1);

// not all APIs will call this library
// I just use rand to represent a probability
if (rand(0,100) == 1) {
    require_once BASEPATH.'lib.php';
    t = new Tester();
    t->func1();
}
```

And the other php file is `lib.php`.

```php
<?php
echo "---- version 1: lib";

class Tester {
    function __construct() {
        echo "---- new Tester in lib.php";
    }

    public function func1() {
        echo "---- Tester.func1()";
    }
}
```

Now I'm going to upload my new version code.

In the new version, I declare a new function `func2()` in `Tester` and delete the old function `func1()`. I call it in the `index.php`.

`index.php`

```php
<?php
echo "version 2: index";

// do some work
sleep(1);

// not all APIs will call this library
// I just use rand to represent a probability
if (rand(0,100) == 1) {
    require_once BASEPATH.'lib.php';
    t = new Tester();
    t->func2();
}
```

`lib.php`

```php
<?php
echo "---- version 2: lib";

class Tester {
    function __construct() {
        echo "---- new Tester in lib.php";
    }

    public function func2() {
        echo "---- Tester.func2()";
    }
}
```

I close the `OpCache`. I upload the `index.php` first and then the other one `lib.php`. At the moment between I finish to upload the `index.php` and begin to upload `lib.php`, a request is running into the "rand case". Then I will get an error about "func2() not defined", because the `lib.php` is still the old one at that time.

If I open the `OpCache`, it's the same if I don't set `validate_timestamps` to 0.

After I set `validate_timestamps` to 0, the opcode will not expire. So I must call `opcache_reset` manually after I finish to upload `index.php` and `lib.php`. At that moment, a request also runs into the "rand case". If the `opcache_reset` operation takes a period of time, and it doesn't block the request running, the error "func2() not defined" may also occur.

How to make all the requests safe when I upgrade my code version?

Comment: I can't really see how any of this potential issues are exclusive to OPcache. If you serve files from a directory where there's an upload in progress you may get mixed revisions (or even incomplete files) anyway.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I'm sorry about my poor expression. I add an example above, could you please take a look again?

Comment: `opcache.validate_timestamps` depends on `opcache.revalidate_freq` :-? But, well, yeah, that's how it works. You need to choose between convenience or performance.

Comment: `opcache.revalidate_freq` depends on `opcache.validate_timestamps`. If you set ` opcache.validate_timestamps` to 0, Apache will not see the `opcache.revalidate_freq` and all opcode will not expire until you call `opcache_reset()` or `opcache_invalidate()`